# VIM navigate tab in Mac OS

Tags: macos, vim

I recently started using OSX 10.8.4, earlier to this I was a Windows user. I installed a Ubuntu 12.04 VM my mac OS. I'm wondering if someone can assist me how to "navigate tabs in VIM" from inside Ubuntu VM. Hovering the mouse over "Tabs" option list commands as: NextTab: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>, PreviousTab:<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> but Mac Pro does not have any <kbd>PageUp</kbd> or <kbd>PageDown</kbd> buttons.

Comment: Try `gt` or `gT` to move forward or backwards a tab.

Comment: For other uses you can hold Function and press up/down for PageUp/Down

Comment: Well, I'm trying to navigate between two terminal windows opened as a tabs in VIM, not sure if "gt" or "gT" is useful. My understanding is both this keys are useful for navigating b/w multiple files opened in a terminal.                                                             I tried option two i.e. fn+UP/DOWN key, UP arrow prints ~ on the terminal prompt but do nothing :(.

Comment: put these in your vimrc

`map <S-H> gT`
`map <S-L> gt`

Then you can press H and L to navigate to left and right respectively.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all advices, but none of the above comments worked for me.
BUT, experimenting for a while key combination that works are:

1. <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> == <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>
2. <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> == <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `gt` and `gT`

(based on the comment of **FDinoff** which IMO could be upgraded to answer)